# Help! Virus on my mac affecting my search engine. It is called "Function Loginput"

Tags: mac, google-chrome, malware, virus

I don't know much about this so please bare with me.
If you think you can help in any way, feel free to ask any questions or anything since these forum sites are my only hope at this point.

I have a Macbook Air running MacOS Big Sur 11.4.

I use Google Chrome as my default browser and I noticed that it kept switching to Yahoo as I tried to search something. This has happened before and all I had to do was reset my Chrome settings, but this time it did not work. I have a Chrome extension called "Function Loginput" that I can't remove, and it prevents me from changing my search engine. There is a picture below that explains what Function Loginput is. I also will include pictures of the extension and what it says when I try to change the search engine.

I have been to numerous sites that seem to be helpful but every one of them has me downloading "Combo Cleaner" which is a mac cleaner application, although its features require payment to fully use.

I have ran the Combo Cleaner, and it does find threats, but to delete them you have to pay, and I can't.

If anyone knows anything about this I would greatly appreciate your help on how to get rid of all of this. Thank you.

Photos below include the description of "Function Loginput" and what it looks like for me when I go to my Chrome extensions, and to search engine settings.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried [other suggestions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252833524) that pop up when you search on the web?

Comment: I've never heard of ComboCleaner. Malwarebytes is a reputable malware tool, which works free, though there are paid options. https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac

Comment: Can we stop putting answers in comments, tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

Golden rule: If searching for 'how to fix stuff' on Mac, never fall for those sites that say "Well, you can do it this way, but it would be much better if you bought our app instead".
They always seem to be able to get to the top of searches, too.

They are invariably scum if not actually malware themselves. They all just repackage the same app in different skins & sell it under many guises, hoping someone new will fall for it every day & pay them.

Second big clue is you've never heard of them before.

Very many of the big, well-known antivirus makers do freeware versions for Mac.
Ones you've heard of;)

You can check out which is currently flavour of the month at [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-macos/), though there is no absolute authority on antivirus certification, at least AV-TEST makes them pay to be tested, so only the serious ones apply. They usually test the payware versions, but you can click through to any of them to see if they do a freeware version too.
There's also Malwarebytes, who no longer subscribe to AV-TEST, after they did really badly in tests & decided not to play any more;) I tend to keep it around for 'just in case' though it's never found anything my main AV didn't.